# Solving an infinitely decaying propelling system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration

I am a HK secondary school student who is taking part in the HKPhO training in my school. I was doing some training questions and struggled with this question:

*A car with initial speed $v_0$ is accelerated with an acceleration $a_0$ for a distance $s$. Each time the car has travelled for a distance $s$, the acceleration of the car is reduced by a factor $λ$ (i.e. $a_1 = λa_0$) and it travels for another distance $s$. The process goes on and on.*

*a. What is the final speed of the car?*

*b. Suppose $λ ≪ 1$, find the approximate value of the final speed of the car by keeping up to the
first-order term in $λ$. Explain briefly the physical meaning of the approximated result.*

Here's my approaches:

1. **Distance intuition.** I tried to write some equations like $v_0t_0+\frac{1}{2}a_0t^2_0=v_1t_1+\frac{1}{2}\lambda a_0t^2_1$.
2. **Speed intuition.** I tried to find the ratio between two substantial time periods. I wrote this: $(2v_0+a_0t_0)t_0=(2(v_0+a_0t_0)+\lambda a_0t_1)t_1$.

However both intuitions failed. Did I miss something or were the intuitions wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your problem speed follows a geometric sequence. Use its properties.

Comment: @manu, the time is variable and I cannot figure out the relationship between time periords so I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is almost there, you only missed the "best" formula to go on: there is in fact a fancy formula relating the acceleration and the speed when travelling a space $s$ with acceleration $a$ and initial velocity $v_0$ given by

$$2 a s = v^2-v_0^2$$

To prove it, just mix the two equations of motion you found

$$v(t)=v_0+at$$
and
$$x(t)=x_0+v_0t+{1\over 2}at^2$$
eliminating the time (i.e. substituting $t={v(t)-v_0 \over a}$ in the second equation).

So, for after first segment, we have
$$2 a_0 s = v_1^2-v_0^2$$ which means $$v_1=2a_0 s+v_0^2$$
for the second segment we get
$$2 a_1 s = v_2^2-v_1^2$$ so that
$$v_2^2=2 a_1 s +v_1^2$$ and using the value of $v_1^2$ we found above and the fact that $a_1=\lambda a_0$ we get:
$$v_2^2=2 \lambda a_0 s + 2a_0 s+v_0^2$$
and we could go on... so this is a recursive formula!

You can use this to solve your problem.

**STOP reading now if you want to complete the homework by yourself (as you should ;) )**

---

---

Indeed we get that, at the end of each segment you travel, the formula for the velocity is

$$2 a_n s = v_n^2-v_n(0)^2$$
where $a_n$ is the acceleration in that segment, $v_n(0)$ the initial velocity.

Because the initial velocity of each segment is the final velocity of the previous segment, $v_n(0)=v_{n-1}$, with $v_1(0)=v_0$.

So

$$2 a_n s = v_n^2-v_{n-1}^2$$

We can rewrite this as

$$v_n^2=2a_ns+v_{n-1}^2$$

Now we use the fact that
$$a_n=\lambda a_{n-1} = \lambda (\lambda a_{n-2}) = .. = \lambda^n a_0$$
so

$$v_n^2=2\lambda^n a_0 s+v_{n-1}^2$$

Again, recursively,

$$v_{n-1}=2\lambda^{n-1} a_0 s+v_{n-2}^2$$ and using the same formula for $v_{n-2}$ we get

$$v^2_{n-1}=2\lambda^{n-1} a_0 s+2\lambda^{n-2} a_0 s+v^2_{n-3}$$
which only stops at $n=1$ when we get

$$v^2_{1}=2 a_0 s+v^2_{0}$$

**Again, STOP HERE if you want to workout the general formula!**

---

---

So the general formula, for $n>=1$, is

$$v^2_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}2\lambda^{i-1} a_0 s+v_0^2$$

so that

$$v^2_2=2\lambda a_0 s+2a_0 s+v_0^2$$ which is the same result we got before!

Here's our final result, then, rearranging a bit:
$$v^2_{n}=v_0^2+2 a_0 s \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lambda^i$$

If $|\lambda| < 1$ you can sum this series for $n\to \infty$ (it is a geometrical series) and get a clean expression for $v_n$ in terms of $\lambda$. Just expand that to the preferred order in $\lambda$ and get the final result!

This leads to
$$v^2_\infty = v_0^2+2 a_0 s \sum_i^\infty \lambda^i = v_0^2+2 a_0 s{1\over 1-\lambda}$$

Otherwise, if $|\lambda| \ll 1$ you can just keep the terms of the sum up to the one containing only $\lambda$ to the first power

$$v^2_\infty = v_0^2+2a_0 s + 2 \lambda a_0 s = v_2^2$$

indicating that if $\lambda$ is very very small only the first to segment actually accelerate the car (that is, to order $\lambda$). This is because if $\lambda\ll 1$ then after a couple of segments you get $a_n\approx 0$ and from then on move at constant speed.

This is equivalent to expanding the result of the infinite series
$$v^2_\infty = v_0^2+2 a_0 s \sum_i^\infty \lambda^i =$$
$$= v_0^2+2 a_0 s{1\over 1-\lambda}\approx v_0^2+2a_0s (1+\lambda)= v_0^2+2a_0s+2\lambda a_0 s$$ where I used $${1\over 1-\lambda}\approx 1+\lambda$$